# Authenticating Bot using the same authentication token of website

Tags: botframework

We are developing the bot application using Microsoft Bot framework and decided to use a website as a channel.

Question is, our website (Channel) is secured with Azure AD Authentication once user is logged in the website.  How we can use the same authenticated user token for the Bot to authenticate the user.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Was my answer adaquate? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a Web Chat sample that shows how to do Single Sign On (SSO) for apps that use Azure Active Directory (AAD)](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/c.sso-for-intranet)

Note that this is not an easy task, but it *is* possible.

**For other users not using AAD**:

- [SSO for Enterprise Apps sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/b.sso-for-enterprise)
- [SSO for Teams Apps sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/d.sso-for-teams)

Comment: The first link is broken ( Page not available). can you guys help on how to implement the SSO in the web channel When the AD (IDP) is common?

Comment: @SelvakumarRathinam Sorry...the Web Chat team recently re-organized their samples. I have updated the links. I'm not sure if this will work or not with common ADs.